# 2 users running a stored procedure concurrently - what happens if DML statements in one execution affect tests/conditions in the parallel execution?

Tags: oracle, plsql, concurrency

Let's say I have a PL/SQL stored procedure for creating sales orders as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE save_order 
(
  o_output_status               OUT BINARY_INTEGER,
  i_customer                    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_product_code                IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_quantity                    IN  BINARY_INTEGER
)
IS

  l_stock_available               BINARY_INTEGER;

BEGIN

  o_output_status := -1;

  SELECT available
    INTO l_stock_available
    FROM stock
   WHERE product = i_product_code
  ;

  IF l_stock_available >= i_quantity THEN

    INSERT INTO sales_orders (order_number, customer, product, quantity)
         VALUES (order_seq.nextval, i_customer, i_product_code, i_quantity)
    ;

    -- hello

    UPDATE stock
       SET available = available - i_quantity
     WHERE product = i_product_code
    ;

    o_output_status := 0;

  END IF;

END save_order;
```

I think that's all pretty straightforward. But what I'd like to know is what happens when 2 users run this stored procedure concurrently. Let's say there's only 1 unit of some product left. If user1 runs the stored procedure first, attempting to create an order for 1 unit, `l_stock_available` gets a value of 1, the `IF` condition evaluates to true and the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` get executed.

Then user2 runs the stored procedure a moment later, also trying to create an order for 1 unit. Let's say the `SELECT INTO` for user2 gets executed by Oracle at the *instant* that user1's execution has reached the comment `hello`. At this point, user2 will also get a value of 1 for `l_stock_available`, the `IF` condition will evaluate to true, and the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` will be executed, bringing the stock level down to -1.

Do I understand correctly? Is this what will happen? How can I avoid this scenario, where 2 orders can be created for the last item in stock?

Comment: Take a read of this -https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/consist.htm

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you understand correctly that the code as written has a race condition.

The simplest fix, assuming that performance requirements permit pessimistic locking, is to add a `FOR UPDATE` to the initial `SELECT` statement.  That locks the particular row in the `STOCKS` table which would cause the second session to block until the first session's transaction either commits or rolls back.  The second session would then see that the stock on hand had been decreased to 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement `DIY` *optimistic locking* (using the similar mechanisms as e.g. JPA uses) add a `VERSION` column to your `stock` table with data type INT initialized with zero.

The initial `select`of your procedure  returns not only the *available quantity* but also the current `VERSION`:

```
  select available, version
  into l_available,l_version
  from stock
  where product_id = i_product_code;
```

If the table has the required quantity you first `UPDATE` it, but *only if the `VERSION` has the same value as returned from the previous query*.

```
update stock
   set available = available - i_quantity,
       version = version + 1
where product_id = 1 and
/* optimistick locking */
version = l_version;
```

Note that 1) the update will fail if the `version` does not match the value you selected.

2. If the update *succeeds* you *increase* the version to block others from performing an concurrent `UPDATE`.

The last step is to check if the update was *succesful* and if so you process the quantity you got.

```
rn := SQL%rowcount; 
if rn = 1 then  /* success */
  insert into sales_orders (thread_id, product_id,quantity,create_ts)
  values(i_thread_id, i_product_code,i_quantity,current_timestamp);
  commit;
end if;
```

If the `UPDATE` changed zero rows (if failed due to changed `VERSION`) you should either retry of return a failure.